# Chrome Extension - oauth authentication through backend express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I've built a web app that has a backend express server which handles oauth authentication via passport.

I'm now trying to build an accompanying browser extension that will share a session with the web app via the express server.

There is one way I've done it that seems to work, which is actually opening the web app's oauth flow in a new window. The authentication technically gets done through the web app, but the extension ends up being able to get the auth status from the server so this "works".

```
const signIn= () => {
chrome.windows.create({
  url: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google-ext",
});
```

};

What I don't like about this solution is that it minimizes the extension.

I've tried doing the following using chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow and calling my same oauth endpoint I would use from the webapp.

```
chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
  {
    url: "http://localhost:5000/auth/google-ext",
    interactive: true,
  },
  (responseUrl) => {
    fetchUser();
  }
);
```

This opens up the oauth sign in page, but after attempting to sign in, I get this error on the extension side:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Authorization page could not be loaded.

And on my server I am getting a

> TokenError: Unauthorized

Here are my express routes and passport strategies:

NOTE: when using the windows.create method, I would use the google client ID for my web app.  For the launchWebAuthFlow method, I use my google extension client ID (both the web app and the extension are under the same google project).

```
    // Extension specific routes
    router.get(
      "auth/google-ext",
      passport.authenticate("google-ext", {
        scope: ["profile", "email"],
      })
    );
    
    router.get(
      "auth/google-ext/callback",
      passport.authenticate("google-ext", {
        failureFlash: true,
      }),
      (req, res) => {
        res.redirect("https://<app-id>.chromiumapp.org/");
      }
    );
    
    // passport.js
    passport.use(
      "google-ext",
      new GoogleStrategy(
        {
          clientID: googleExtensionClientID,
          clientSecret: googleClientSecret,
          callbackURL: "/auth/google-ext/callback",
          proxy: true,
        },
        async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
          const existingUser = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });
    
          if (existingUser) {
            return done(null, existingUser);
          }
    
          const user = await new User({
            name: profile.name,
            email: profile.emails[0].value,
            googleId: profile.id,
          }).save();
          done(null, user);
        }
      )
    );
```

I've been trying to figure this out for awhile but have been unable to figure it out.  Is what I am trying to do even possible?  Do I have use google's getAuthToken instead?

EDIT:

It appears if I use my web app client ID for the passport strategy, the oauth flow works correctly, and my /auth/google-ext/callback is receiving a `req.user`.  However, the session does not appear to be getting saved anywhere, ie, a follow up request to retrieve the `req.user` results in a null/undefined.

Here is my server `index.js`

```
const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({ origin: "chrome-extension://<app-id>" })
);

app.use(express.json());

app.use(
  cookieSession({
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    keys: [cookieKey],
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?